# Use default ListDensityPlot color scheme in ArrayPlot?

Tags: plotting, color

I have some data that I would like to display in an `ArrayPlot`. I like the default color scheme of `ListDensityPlot` (Mathematica 10); is there a way I can use that same color scheme in `ArrayPlot`? In other words, how can I extract the default `ColorFunction` used in `ListDensityPlot` (or `DensityPlot`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a sample array with {x, y, z} values

```
array = {{1, 0, 0, 0.3}, {1, 1, 0, 0.3}, {1, 0, 1, 0.7}}
```

We make a `ListDensityPlot`

```
listDensityPlot = ListDensityPlot[array]
```

which produces

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We are lucky because we can "see" the color function using options:

```
Options[listDensityPlot]
```

I won't show them all but one item of interest is:

```
"DefaultColorFunction" -> "M10DefaultDensityGradient"
```

So all that need be done is

```
ArrayPlot[array, ColorFunction -> "M10DefaultDensityGradient"]
```

which results in

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Did not know about Options, looks very useful in general. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

OK I found a simple if unelegant solution.

The idea is to turn off ColorFunctionScaling and generate a list of DensityPlots where each DensityPlot just shows a constant value from 0 to 1, then take the color from each plot and interpolate between them. Certainly not the most efficient solution but it works.

```
defaultColorGetter[zVal_] := DominantColors[ListDensityPlot[zVal*{{1, 1}, {1, 1}}, Frame -> False, ColorFunctionScaling -> False], 1][[1]];
colors = Table[defaultColorGetter[z], {z, 0, 1, 0.1}];
approximateDefaultColorFunction[z_] := Blend[colors, z];
```

Setting ColorFunction -> approximateDefaultColorFunction in ArrayPlot now gives the desired behavior:

[image]